# Python socket Buffering: Message Framing

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am receiving the data stream(46 Bytes) from external hardware(Zigbee receiver) to PC on a TCP/IP socket. Then by using Python programming,iam trying to extract the message from the received data stream from TCP/IP socket.

my python source code and extracted data from the data stream, given in the bellow link

https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1pYASqImWm4HkKrDbeeal8fTBsh_GojBQLXixxbMQBlU

As we know "TCP/IP operate on stream of data, never by packets"

i could able extract the data, if i received the complete packet in a single stream. but some times, the single packet is received in two data streams(broken), that time i couldn't extract my message from the stream.

i am not more familier with python programming, so can anyone help me to slove this problem.

I am looking for any good example(programming) to manage the breaking of incomming data stream on a TCP/IP socket, by storing those stream in a buffer as complete packet and then extract the message by using delimiters.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import socket

def connect(addr):
    con = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    con.connect(addr)
    return con 

addr = ('127.0.0.1', 7777)
client_socket = connect(addr)
packet_size = 46
data = ""
while True:
    while len(data) < packet_size:
        d = client_socket.recv(1024)
        if not d:
            client_socket.close()
            client_socket = connect(addr) 
        else:
            data += d
    packet, data = data[:packet_size], data[packet_size:]
    lqi = ord(packet[27])
    ...
```

Comment: +1, my only concern is you should check if `recv` doesn't return an empty string to indicate closed connection.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the code to reconnect when connection is closed.

Comment: Its working good, now i didnt get any break in the data stream, i could receive the data stream continuesly.But, Still i experiance data loss in the stream,

Comment: i have few question regarding this data loss. in TCP/IP socket